# java ArrayList with two columns

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to update a table with two columns and I have created a class

```
public class Country {

    private String url;
    private String search;

    public Country(String url, String search) {

        this.url = url;
        this.search = search;
    }

    // ...
}

List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
countries.add(new Country(urls, txt));
...
```

Countries has a data `{java.com.main@yfxse34567}`
Could be `{www.google.com, main string...}`

How can I put a proper data into countries list

Comment: override to string...wait... what do you mean with put proper data????

Answer (score 0):

Override the toString() method

**Example**

```
List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>() {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "{";
        for (int index= 0; index < size(); index++){
            result = result.concat(this.get(index).url);
            if (index != size()-1) {
                result = result.concat(", ");
            }
        }
        result = result.concat("}");
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I update a table with two columns from the string?

Comment: do not use toString if you want to add the string in table. Basically you are adding country object to te list. Thus you easily to list.get(). With the retrieved country object, you cal call country.getUrl(), country.getText() and add those to the correct columns in table

Answer (score 0):

For me your solution should work, however try to instantiate the parent first and then add the instance ... Something like

```
Country instanceCountry = new Country();
instanceCountry.setUrl("www.google.com");
instanceCountry.setSearch("xpto");

countries.add(instanceCountry);
```

**Do not forget to generate the Getters and Setters**